# Finding primes in python

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7, math, primes

I know that python is "slow as dirt", but i would like to make a fast and efficient program that finds primes. This is what i have:

```
    num = 5 #Start at five, 2 and 3 are printed manually and 4 is a        multiple of 2
    print("2")
    print("3")

def isPrime(n):
#It uses the fact that a prime (except 2 and 3) is of form 6k - 1 or 6k + 1 and looks only at divisors of this form.

    i = 5
    w = 2
    while (i * i <= n): #You only need to check up too the square root of n
        if (n % i == 0): #If n is divisable by i, it is not a prime
            return False
        i += w
        w = 6 - w
    return True #If it isn´t ruled out by now, it is a prime


while True:
    if ((num % 2 != 0) and (num % 3 != 0)): #save time, only run the     function of numbers that are not multiples of 2 or 3
        if (isPrime(num) == True):
            print(num) #print the now proved prime out to the screen
    num += 2 #You only need to check odd numbers
```

Now comes my questions: 
-Does this print out ALL prime numbers?
-Does this print out any numbers that aren't primes?
-Are there more efficient ways(there probably are)?
-How far will this go(limitations of python), and are there any ways to increase upper limit?

Using python 2.7.12

Comment: Very much related, but not an exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2068372/1639625

Comment: You cannot just walk into the Church of Python and say that *"it is slow as dirt"*.. Even if it is.

Comment: You can use *Miller-Rabin* filtering, *Pocklington tests*, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this print out ALL prime numbers?

There are infinitely many primes, as demonstrated by Euclid around 300 BC. So the answer to that question is most likely no.

> Does this print out any numbers that aren't primes?

By the looks of it, it doesn't. However, to be sure; why not write a unit test?

> Are there more efficient ways(there probably are)? -How far will this go(limitations of python), and are there any ways to increase upper limit?

See [Fastest way to list all primes below N](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068372/fastest-way-to-list-all-primes-below-n) or [Finding the 10001st prime - how to optimize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32333888/finding-the-10001st-prime-how-to-optimize?rq=1)

Comment: With "all primes", I meant that the program doesn't skip any. I am wondering if there is any bugs that would do e.g. 2, 3, 7, 11(skipping 5), are there numbers that will not be printed using my script?

Comment: Again; I would recommend writing a unit test. It is of course impossible to test every case due to the infinite nature of prime numbers. Or you could just use one of the already tried-and-tested solutions in the links suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

Checking for num % 2 != 0 even though you increment by 2 each time seems pointless.

I have found that this algorithm is faster:

```
primes=[]

n=3

print("2")
while True:
    is_prime=True
    for prime in primes:
        if n % prime ==0:
            is_prime=False
            break
        if prime*prime>n:
            break

    if is_prime:
        primes.append(n)
        print (n)

    n+=2
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple. The function below returns `True` if `num` is a prime, otherwise `False`. Here, if we find a factor, other than 1 and itself, then we early stop the iterations because the number is not a prime.

```
def is_this_a_prime(num):
    if num < 2 : return False # primes must be greater than 1
    for i in range(2,num): # for all integers between 2 and num
        if(num % i == 0): # search if num has a factor other than 1 and itself
            return False # if it does break, no need to search further, return False
    return True # if it doesn't we reached that point, so num is a prime, return True
```

Comment: This isn't more efficient than mine, i think? This checks all potential factors up to "num" itself, but you know you never have to check anything above the square root of n

Comment: Hello @DriverUpdate. It actually doesn't ! You can check it yourself. When a factor is detected other than 1 or the number itself, I return false.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to optimize the code a bit, and this is what I've done.Instead of running the loop for n or n/2 times, I've done it using a conditional statements.(I think it's a bit faster)

```
def prime(num1, num2):
import math
def_ = [2,3,5,7,11]
result = []
for i in range(num1, num2):
    if i%2!=0 and i%3!=0 and i%5!=0 and i%7!=0 and i%11!=0:
        x = str(math.sqrt(i)).split('.')
        if int(x[1][0]) > 0:
            result.append(i)
    else:
        continue

return def_+result if num1 < 12 else result
```

Comment: let me know if there are any bugs